# Add multiple items into a ListBox from multiple TextBoxes

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox

I want to create a basket for a product and the user enters the product name, quantity and price and then to be put into a list box on the same line. Here is what I have so far

```
private void addToBasket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string product = productName.Text;
        decimal quan = quantity.Value;
        int quant = Convert.ToInt32(quan);
        string p = this.price.Text;
        int price = Convert.ToInt32(p);
        basket.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem(product, quan, price));
    }
}

internal class ListBoxItem
{
    private string product;
    private decimal quan;
    private int price;

    public ListBoxItem(string product, decimal quan, int price)
    {
        this.product = product;
        this.quan = quan;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

When I click add it puts in the list box: BasketForm.ListBoxItem with no values relating to what I entered into the text box

Comment: You may need to set the ListBoxItem.DisplayMember and ValueMember in order to see anything other than the object type.

Answer (score 0):

When objects are bound to a (listbox) control, said control will by default use the ToString method to display the value. You could just override said method in your ListBoxItem class to make any control display the quantity, the item name and the unit price:

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}x {1} @{2}", quan, product, price);
    }
```

Comment: Inside your class. Each class implements the ToString method, and here we override it to return the object's properties. Alternatively, as suggested by @JayF1, you can set the ListBoxes DisplayMember to the product's name (or anything else).